# How to add a menu to the FloatingActionButton in the android design library updated recently?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, android-design-library

I was trying to use the `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` in my project and I was wondering how do I add pop up menu options to the button on click.

I also wanted to know how to animate the button `onClick()`.
Please help me out with this.

Comment: Currently it is not supported by official FloatingActionButton

Comment: I also want to do that using Design Library. Waiting for update.